# Proxy requests to nginx web application through Express Server: Issues

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nginx, proxy

I have quite a big question to ask about Nginx and Express Server to get some help, I am going to split it into three parts to make it easier to understand and get help.

**1. Nginx Application**
This nginx app is a Docker Container with the following.

DockerFile:

```
# Use the official nginx image as the base image
FROM nginx

# Create directories in the container for each app
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/nginx/html/app /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryappadmin /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryapplogin

# Remove the default nginx configuration file
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Copy the nginx configuration file to the container
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy production files to the container
COPY ./diaryapp-react/build /usr/share/nginx/html/app
COPY ./diaryappadmin-react/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryappadmin
COPY ./ClientAuthWeb/public /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryapplogin

# Set the working directory to the nginx configuration directory
WORKDIR /etc/nginx

# Expose port 80 for the web server
EXPOSE 80

# Start the nginx web server in the foreground
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # Serve files for diaryapp
        location /app {
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache';
            expires 0;

            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/app;

            index index.html;
        }

        # Serve files for diaryappadmin
        location /diaryappadmin {
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache';
            expires 0;

            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryappadmin;

            index index.html;
        }

        # Serve files for diaryapplogin
        location /diaryapplogin {
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
            add_header Cache-Control 'no-cache';
            expires 0;

            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryapplogin;
            index login.html;
        }

        # Additional configuration for diaryapplogin
        location = /diaryapplogin/login.html {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryapplogin/login.html;
        }

        location = /diaryapplogin/thankyou.html {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryapplogin/thankyou.html;
        }

        location = /diaryapplogin/wrong.html {
            alias /usr/share/nginx/html/diaryapplogin/wrong.html;
        }

        # Serve /api/ to the server / entrypoint
        location /api/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.144:7050/;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_read_timeout 43200; # 12h timeout for long term connections
        }

        # Serve /flyonsapi/ to the flyons API server / entrypoint
        location /flyonsapi/ {
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.144:4070/;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Type;
            proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            proxy_read_timeout 43200; # 12h timeout for long term connections
        }

        # Disable server tokens for security reasons
        server_tokens off;

        # Increase the maximum request size to 50 MB
        client_max_body_size 50m;

        # Enable gzip compression for faster page loading
        gzip on;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Set default cache control headers
        add_header Cache-Control "no-store";

        # Include the mime types file
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        # Serve static files from the /usr/share/nginx/html directory
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Disable caching for static files
        location ~* \.(css|js|ico)$ {
            expires -1;
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
        }
    }
}
```

Insight to the part 1: The application is supposed to host three different applications (2 react, 1 plain HTML), at their respective endpoints in the conf file. As well as to API endpoints to Express servers. This configuration works great in a docker container when accessing at the respective port on localhost.

**2. Proxy Express Server**
This express server is meant to proxy requests and set cookies based on the subdomain and the leading / endpoint.

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const proxy = require('express-http-proxy');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// Import the config
const config = require('./config.json');

// Make an express instance
const app = express();

// Include dependencies for the express instance
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']
}));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Connect to the Flyons Database
var MongoDB;
mongoose.connect(config.database.url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Database connection succeeded!');
        MongoDB = mongoose.connection;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error('Error with MongoDB', err);
        process.exit(1);
    });

// Use cookie-parser middleware
app.use(cookieParser());

// Middleware to handle application redirection
app.use(async (request, response, next) => {
    const subdomain = request.subdomains[0];
    const requestedPath = request.path;

    try {
        // Check if organisation exists
        const organisationData = await MongoDB.collection('flyons_organisations').findOne({ orgDomain: subdomain });
        if (!organisationData) {
            throw new Error('Organization not found');
        }

        // Look up information about the product
        const productInfo = await MongoDB.collection('flyons_products').findOne({ productEndpoint: requestedPath });
        if (!productInfo) {
            throw new Error('Product information not found');
        }

        // Check if any registered product matches the productId and orgId
        const registeredProduct = await MongoDB.collection('flyons_registeredproducts').findOne({ orgId: organisationData.orgId, productId: productInfo.productId });
        if (!registeredProduct) {
            throw new Error('Invalid endpoint for the organization');
        }

        // Set the cookie
        response.cookie('orgID', organisationData.orgId, { domain: `${subdomain}.flyons.org`, httpOnly: true });

        // If everything is valid, proceed to proxy the request with a dynamic target
        const dynamicProxy = proxy(`http://${productInfo.productIp}`);
        dynamicProxy(request, response, next);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        response.status(404).send('Not Found');
    }
});

// A little info about the server at /
app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Welcome to the Flyons Site Redirection Service! Copyright 2024 Flyons.');
});

// Start the server
app.listen(config.server.port, () => {
    console.log('Welcome to the Flyons Site Redirection Service! Copyright 2024 Flyons.');
    console.log(`Express server started on port ${config.server.port}`);
});
```

Insight to part 2: This Express server is meant to proxy each request to a specified IP in the db based on the following / and also uses the subdomain as a reference for which org is accessing the application. For example, If i were to access testorg.example.com/diary, then the app would be diary and be 'registered' under testorg as the organization.

**3. Dummy Data from the DB**
There are three main components to make this express work, here is some data to help from the MongodDB database with the respective collection names.

flyons_organisations:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6587b8d6f17d7551faaffe98"
  },
  "orgName": "Testorg",
  "orgEmail": "exampleguy@gmail.com",
  "orgPhone": "123456789",
  "orgDomain": "testorg",
  "orgPassword": "the-hashed-password",
  "orgId": "f81823af-7a9a-4801-a512-27e367f9227d",
  "__v": 0
}
```

flyons_products:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6587bb4bb9e09e5f2dd74ab6"
  },
  "productName": "Flyons Diary App",
  "productPrice": "$56",
  "productPaymentCycle": "Monthly",
  "productId": "eddfae56c5bda45a6295dd6f0978c892",
  "unlockCode": "123aBc",
  "productEndpoint": "/diary",
  "productIp": "192.168.0.144:6072",
  "productAdminEndpoint": "/diaryappadmin",
  "__v": 0
}
```

flyons_registeredproducts:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "659b47b148d6b7444f1077af"
  },
  "productId": "eddfae56c5bda45a6295dd6f0978c892",
  "productName": "Flyons Diary App",
  "productAdminManagePage": "https://testorg.flyons.org/diary/diaryappadmin",
  "orgId": "f81823af-7a9a-4801-a512-27e367f9227d",
  "usedUnlockCode": true,
  "__v": 0
}
```

Insight into part 3: This data is important, first the server checks to see if the org is valid using the respective subdomain to get the orgId, with this it checks the products for an productEndpoint matching the on in the Url (/diary in this case). If exists it checks if the org has this application registered and then proxies that request to the appropriate application web server. In this case the nginx server from before.

**The Problem:**

Every time i want to access the diary application through the server (and yes i am using cloudflare tunnel to forware to application the respective test domains and what not), it just says not found from the express server or the nginx server returns 404 as well. The most common error i get in nginx is this:

```
2024-01-13 14:54:29 2024/01/13 04:54:29 [error] 20#20: *19 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/diary" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /diary HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.0.144:7051"
2024-01-13 14:54:29 172.17.0.1 - - [13/Jan/2024:04:54:29 +0000] "GET /diary HTTP/1.1" 404 118 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:121.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/121.0"
```

Just a clarification from the DockerFile, the website files are NOT under the /diary directory, so my main question is, how on earth do i stop NGINX from thinking that the /diary endpoint for the express servers reference is apart of the file path in the NGINX server. The file path should look like it is copied from the DockerFile without the /diary bit.

Also if see any errors, mistakes, or have an idea/suggestion please post!

Thanks so much for all the help.